# How to put graphs in Playwright report

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

Im currently playing around with playwright(automate several test)/typescript  and i want a general donut graph and/or in each test suite in the reporter

I tried to use mochawesome but the reporter grabs the setup suite as the only test in the report, i see 3 test in total but visible only one

[image: The failed test look like this]

I want to know how could i implement graphs in the report while using playwright

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.